# EntityTransaction never rollsback, throws exception saying Transaction is not active

Tags: jpa

I am working on a standalone application of java using JPA for object persistence and the provider is Hibernate. Now when i persist an entity and call commit() of EntityTransaction, entity is persisted to database. If there is a database error on constraints etc there is an exception and when i try to rollback i get an  java.lang.IllegalStateException. Nothing gets committed.

I have a Role entity  which uses a table generation strategy to generate primary key for this entity. Whenever commit fails and next time i save a role the sequence generated for previous save is lost and this time it is an incremented one. This problem persists for Auto increment strategy too. I did not face this problem while working with hibernate SessionFactory.

code :

Role.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(schema="System")
    public class Role extends PrincipalEntityBase{

    @TableGenerator(schema="System",table="MasterSequence", valueColumnName="Sequence",
        pkColumnName="GenKey",pkColumnValue="Role_ID",
        name="System.Role", allocationSize=0)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="System.Role",strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name="Role_ID")
private Long role_ID;

@Column(name="RoleName")
private String roleName;

    public Role() {
    }

public Long getRole_ID() {
    return this.role_ID;
}

public void setRole_ID(Long role_ID) {
    this.role_ID = role_ID;
}

public String getRoleName() {
    return this.roleName;
}

public void setRoleName(String roleName) {
    this.roleName = roleName;
}
}
```

Main.java

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
            Role r = new Role();
    r.setRoleName("Hello");
    EntityManager em = persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test")
            .createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tr = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        tr.begin();
        em.persist(r);
        tr.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tr.rollback();
        System.out.println("Rolled back");
    }
    }
```

StackTrace :

```
    javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:93)
at com.mis.jpa.test.main.Main.main(Main.java:32)
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.mis.entity.system.Role]
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1235)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1168)
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:81)
... 1 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.mis.entity.system.Role]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transaction not active
at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:104)
at com.mis.jpa.test.main.Main.main(Main.java:35)
```

Db server is MSSQL server.

Persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>com.mis.entity.system.Role</class>

    <properties>

        <!-- Connection properties -->
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"             value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.2:1433;databaseName=jparesearch" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin" />

        <!-- JPA Provider Settings -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 4):

First question: why rollback fails. The rollback fails because it's not some code before the commit which has thrown the exception, but the commit itself. If commit throws a RollbackException, then it means the commit has failed and has thus transformed the commit into a rollback and made the transaction inactive. Just test if the transaction is active before rollbacking the transaction.

Second question: why are there holes in the sequence of generated IDs. The generator, when asked for a new ID, increments the sequence number in its own short-lived transaction. So, if your transaction rolls back and thus doesn't use the generated ID, there will be a hole in the sequence because the increment in the table has already been committed. If it didn't use its own short-lived transaction, then, either you would have lots of conflicts (because several long transactions would see the same current value and only increment it later), or the throughput would be very low, because all transactions wanting an ID would have to wait for the previous transaction to complete.

Holes are unavoidable. Deal with them.

Comment: Thank you so much. You are right if the rollback on the sequence too takes place then there will be a performance problem as you have explained. I never thought of this aspect. Thanks again.